# How does a parser for the infix notation detect the missing multiplication sign?

Tags: parsing, syntax, ebnf

I am writing a parser that parses mathematical expressions based on a syntax diagram very similar to [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram#/media/File:Example_syntax_diagram_3.svg).

I have not found a way to handle a missing multiplication sign (for example in `3(x+y)`). Where in the syntax diagram do I have to handle this?

Comment: `3(x+y)` is not a valid expression in the grammar you link to. You could make `*` optional (implicit), if you like, but that's not how that grammar currently is.

Comment: Instead of changing your question radically, ask a new question and include a link to the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd make the `*` optional in the definition of `term`.

ASCII diagram:

```
o-->-->--[factor]->-->--o
    /               \
    \               /
     ---<--[*]--<---
         \     /
          --<--
```

Comment: Ok. I understand this but please see my edits to the question since I wanted to ask something that is more related to the actual code.

Comment: @user1574054 That's a completely new question. I don't know C#, sorry.