# Right associative operator in a mathematical expression parser

Tags: c#, parsing, associative, infix-notation, infix-operator

Finally, coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631677/parsing-a-mathematical-expression-with-missing-multiplication-signs), the problem remains, that this subparser...

```
private static void Factor(Scanner scanner, ref TermNode currentTree, ref Token currentToken)
{
    Exponent(scanner, ref currentTree, ref currentToken);

    while (currentToken is OperatorToken && ((OperatorToken)currentToken).OperatorChar == '^') // So long as the token is ^
    {
        TermNode node = new TermNode(currentTree, null, currentToken);
        currentTree = null;
        scanner.MoveNext();
        currentToken = scanner.Current;
        Exponent(scanner, ref currentTree, ref currentToken);
        node.RightChild = currentTree;
        currentTree = node;
    }
}
```

...does not handle the exponential operator ("^") correctly. This is due to the fact that it is right associative. The code above handles it as if it was left associative.

For example: The text `e^x^2` is interpreted as `(e^x)^2`. However, the correct "interpretation" would be `e^(x^2)`.

I have already tried something like this:

```
if (/* The current token is ^ */)
{
    TermNode node = new TermNode(tree, null, currentToken);
    tree = null;
    scanner.MoveNext();
    currentToken = scanner.Current;
    Exponent(ref tree);
    node.RightChild = tree;
    tree = node;
}
while (/* The current token is ^  */)
{
    TermNode detachedExponent = tree.RightChild;
    TermNode oldTree = tree;
    Token token = currentToken;
    tree.RightChild = null;
    tree = null;
    scanner.MoveNext();
    currentToken = scanner.Current;
    Exponent(ref tree);
    oldTree.RightChild = new TermNode(distachedExponent, tree, token);
    tree = oldTree;
}
```

Which only works for two sequential "^"-expressions. Not something like `e^x^y^z` (which would be `e^(x^(y^z))` and not `e^((x^y)^z)` like the parser claims... What am I missing?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I assume "how can I make this parser handle right-associative operators like ^ correctly?".

Comment: @JerryFederspiel Yes, yes it is.

Comment: This is easy.  *First* write the BNF you wish to accept.  Then code the recursive descent parser the way I suggested.   if the operator is right-associative, the grammar will specify that way, and your parser will work accordingly.    I showed you how in your previous question; I leave it to your carry it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `a^b`, and you see `^c`, you inject it into the RHS of the top-level `^`, creating `a^(b^c)`, and leave yourself with the resulting full expression. When you then see `^d`, you again inject it into the RHS of the top-level `^`, creating `a^((b^c)^d)`. You shouldn't be injecting it into the RHS of the top-level `^`, but into the right/inner-most `^` expression. To achieve that, simply keep track of that expression in a separate variable. Then, instead of modifying the top level expression's `RightChild` property, modify the child's.